# Reserve instance when running less than 24 hours a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I would like to know the best solution.

I have an instance of **t3.medium** type running 6 hours a day.
Does it make sense for me to buy **t3.nano** type reserved instance, if so, how many instances? Or does it not pay to buy a reserved instance?

Answer (score 2):

From a purely mathematical viewpoint, in US regions a t3.medium Linux instance would cost:

- **On-Demand:** $0.0416 per Hour x 6 hours per day x 5 days per week x 52 weeks = $64.896 per year (Or ~$90 if 7 days per week)
- **1-Year upfront Reserved instance:** $213 per year
- **3-Year upfront Reserved instance:** $412 = $137 per year

So, the cheapest option is **On-Demand**.

An alternative is a [Scheduled Reserved Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-scheduled-instances.html), which "are a good choice for workloads that do not run continuously, but do run on a regular schedule." However, it seems that this option has been removed from the Management Console in some regions.

A Reserved Instance also includes a capacity reservation in case of capacity constraints, which makes it attractive beyond merely price.

Answer (score 2):

The **maximum discount** you can get is **~62%** for **3 year, 100% upfront**. Since you running the instance for only 6 hours / day, it makes no financial sense to reserve your instance.